# What folder is this code signifying?

Tags: installation, command-line, kinect

I am trying to install OpenNi on ubuntu and have found some decent looking instructions but I am not sure what I need to do for this one specific case.  [Here are the instructions](http://mitchtech.net/ubuntu-kinect-openni-primesense/)

and here is the line that is tripping me up:

```
cd OpenNI/Platform/Linux/CreateRedist/
chmod +x RedistMaker
./RedistMaker
cd ../Redist/OpenNI-Bin-Dev-Linux-x64-v1.5.2.23/
sudo ./install.sh
```

I don't know what folder the `cd ../Redist/OpenNI-Bin-Dev-Linux-x64-v1.5.2.23/` line is talking about and can't find it anywhere.  Does anyone know what this is?

Answer (score 0):

This is a command `./RedistMaker` and it will (/should) create the directories and files you need. The `cd ../Redist/OpenNI-Bin-Dev-Linux-x64-v1.5.2.23/` should get you from the directory where you executed the command to 1 directory up and then into a new directory `Redist` into a new directory `OpenNI-Bin-Dev-Linux-x64-v1.5.2.23`. 
Ans in there there should be a file named `install.sh`.

So the starting spot where you should find `Redist` should be `OpenNI/Platform/Linux/`.

Comment: yeah I have looked in nearly every folder but it isn't there...

Comment: I suppose the version could have been updated and changed a few things around